# The network path was not found -Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am getting this error when I try to connect to Azure SQL Server.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I’ve been using the server and the databases under it for several months without a problem. The error starts after I deleted virtual network, public ip, virtual and local gateways, and some resources I created and played with. I’ve been searching the web the whole day but couldn’t find the right solution.

My application that was deployed outside my network that's working find previously can no longer connect. I also set the firewall to accept all ip.

Comment: This error occurs between your local desktop and the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the IP address of the server you're trying to connect from might've changed due to your changing of network infrastructure, and now your Azure SQL instance is denying the inbound connection. Get the outbound IP address of the computer you're trying to connect from, then check your Azure SQL Server's firewall rules to make sure that the address you're trying to connect to is whitelisted.

Comment: I already set the Azure SQL Server firewall to accept all IP but still unable to connect. I also thought it has something to do with server IP.